# Use extbase service in sr_feuser_register hook

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-4.5

I have a hook that gets successfully called

```
class tx_srfeuserregister_MyHooksHandler {
  public function registrationProcess_afterSaveCreate ($recordArray, &$invokingObj) {
    var_dump($recordArray); //i get here
  }
}
```

thanks to being registered in the sr_feuser_register/ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['sr_feuser_register']['tx_srfeuserregister_pi1']['registrationProcess'][] = 'EXT:sr_feuser_register/hooks/class.tx_srfeuserregister_MyHooksHandler.php:&tx_srfeuserregister_MyHooksHandler';
```

To do useful things here, and without copy/pasting code, I'd like to call a service method from an extbase service that is located in another extension

typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Classes/Domain/Service/Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Service_EntityFactory.php

How do I inject that into my hook, or get it through the object factory? I've tried a couple of things and googled a lot, but could not figure it out.

Comment: Post the attempts you did and the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get an instance of the extbase object manager, get your service and call your method. Something like this:

```
    /**
     * @var Tx_Extbase_Object_ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var Tx_MyExt_Service_MyService
     */
    protected $myService;

    public function registrationProcess_afterSaveCreate ($recordArray, &$invokingObj) {
        $this->initializeObjects();
        // Now you can use your Service.
        $this->myService->myMethod($recordArray);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeObjects() {
        if (empty($this->objectManager)) {
            $this->objectManager = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Object_ObjectManager');
        }
        if (empty($this->myService)) {
            $this->myService = $this->objectManager->get('Tx_MyExt_Service_MyService');
        }
    }
```